# How to extend an existing method of a class without subclassing?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-category

I am not sure if it is possible but my question is the following.
I want to add one more line to the end of `init` method of a class that exists within `UIKit`; I have no access to the implementation of existing `init` method and I want to modify it.

Let's say I want to add

```
NSLog(@"Hello world!");
```

to the end of `initWithNibName` method of `UIViewController`. Is it possible?

Comment: without subClass it is no possible

Answer (score 1):

You can swizzle method implementation. Check [this](http://cocoadev.com/MethodSwizzling).

Something like:

1. Swizzle UIKitMethod => yourUIKitMethod,
2. In yourUIKitMethod implementation you call UIKitMethod implementation and add your NSLog line.

But that's not a good idea as far as it changes method implementation in ALL instances of a class.

UPD: Oh, I've just found an [article right about what I'm suggesting](http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/HP-Software-Developers-Blog/Objective-C-Runtime-method-swizzling-in-a-nutshell/ba-p/6122133#.UnpMda0mzx4).

Comment: Thanks for answer. But, you can add a category and write yourUIKitMethod into it, you do not have to swizzle I guess.

Comment: @MertBuran, of course you could do that, and that's way better then method swizzling. But your question was about adding code to existing method without subclassing (for example init as you've stated). With method swizzling you call init and it executes yourInit's implementation, with category you have to call yourInit. Overriding existing methods in categories is strongly discouraged by Apple.